# Check to see if any duplicate index values exist within an array?

Tags: java, arrays

So basically, I have one array, with ten values...

```
int[] input = new int[10];
```

The user controls the input to each value.

What would be a good technique to check to see if any of the values inside of the array are equal to any of the other values?

Edit:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    P2 numbers = new P2();

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.input.length; i++) {
        numbers.input[i] = numbers.scan.nextInt();
    }
    numbers.Check();
    if (numbers.Check()) { System.out.println("Duplicate"); }
    if (numbers.Check() == false) { System.out.println("NOT Duplicate"); }
}

public boolean Check() {
        int length = input.length;
        for(int i : input) {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
                if(input[i] == input[j]) return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The codes works ask long as duplicate numbers are index-neighbors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really only have ten values in the array, you're better off with a double-nested loop that breaks when it finds a duplicate.

```
int length = input.length;
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
        if(intput[i] == input[j]) return true;
    }
}​
```

If you're expecting to scale up to a large number, you're better off populating a hashset and breaking when you find a value that's already in the Hashset.

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for(int i : input) {
    if(set.contains(i)) return true;
    set.add(i);
}​
```

Comment: `i` is being given input values, but then used as an index.

Comment: ` for(int j = i + 1; j < length; j++)` won't this `for` loop only check the index right above the previous one?

Comment: A `BitSet` would be much more efficient for finding duplicate `ints`.

Comment: @Johannes: it will only check the indices after the current `i` value. This does two things: it avoids getting a false positive by checking `array[1]` against itself, and it cuts the number of comparisons in half because if you know `array[1] != array[2]`, then you can assume `array[2] != array[1]`.

Comment: @Johannes with only one array, the indexes at lower values of `j` have already been checked that they are not duplicated. If there were two different arrays being compared then you would start `j` at `0` (and use a different length)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Yes, but if you enter `1` then `2` then `1` as your values, it will not detect any duplicates, even though there are.

Comment: @Stephen Denne: Could you provide a code example of using a BitSet for this purpose?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior will do, but I've realised its only efficient if the stored ints are small.

Comment: @Johannes: if you enter 1, 2, 1, then you will find that array[0] == array[2] (they are both `1`) and return. It will never have the need to check array[2] == array[0].

Comment: @Stephen Denne: That makes sense to me. Sort of like using a bucket sort?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: I've posted my code up top. I'm probably missing something very obvious!

Comment: @Johannes: Sorry, my original code had a bug in it that Stephen found. Please update your code with my current code.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Yup! That was it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: I know the question has been answered, but I'm curious, if I wanted to `System.out.println();` the array, excluding the duplicates, would there be an easy way to integrate that with the current code, or would that require giving the code a face-lift?

Comment: @Johannes: You'd follow the same general pattern as the second code sample (with the HashSet), but the first line of the `for` loop would be `if(!set.contains(i)) System.out.println(i);`. If you want to do both (print non-duplicates, then return true if there were duplicates), you'd have to use a boolean variable to track whether you had encountered a duplicate, which would only be slightly more complex. I personally wouldn't combine the two, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could

1. compare all values in two loops (inefficient)
2. sort the array and then only compare adjacent values. This is more efficient, especially for longer arrays.

The first one is very easy to implement and if your array only has a length of 10, this should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If the stored `int` values are small non-negative values, then a [`BitSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) might be appropriate:

```
BitSet set = new BitSet();
for(int i : input) {
    if(set.get(i)) return true;
    set.set(i);
}​
```

If you instead have a wide range of values, and lots of them, but a low likelihood of there being a duplicate (i.e. you expect there to be no duplicates, and simply need to confirm that), you can hash the ints, and use a BitSet(8192) of the low 13 bits of the hash (for example). That only uses roughly 1k. This can be used to easily confirm that there are no duplicates, but if it does find a hash collision, then you need to re-check with a less efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also sort the array and scan quickly for duplicates. Compared to building a hashset, it won't use as much memory, but will be slower.